# Implement KoGrid.JS in SPEAK UI page

Tags: knockout.js, sitecore, sitecore8, kogrid, sitecore-speak-ui

I need to integrate KoGrid.JS in one of my SPEAK UI custom component page.

But I am facing below issues:

Getting KO is undefined error because it's NOT getting reference of "Knockout.JS"

Reason we found - Speak UI renders Knockout.js at the end after rendering our own Custom JS files. So we are not able to using any Knockout functions.

How to implement Knockout Grid having features like KOGrid.JS?

Comment: Without [showing some code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), your question has a good chance of being closed.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're not executing any code until the document is fully loaded (javascript and everything).  Use [jQuery's document.ready handler](https://api.jquery.com/ready/):

```
$(function() {
    var vm = new viewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(vm);
});
```